# Why pointer not giving its Ascii Value?

Tags: c, pointers

This is my current code as folows:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
  /* code */
  char a[5] = {'a','b'};
  int *p =a;
  printf("%d\n", *p);
return 0;
}
```

When I execute my code it is showing `25185` instead of giving me an ASCII value.

Why is this happening?

Thank you

Comment: `int *p =a;` is UB when alignment is not correct.  I believe anti-aliasing also leads to _undefined behaviour_ (UB) here.  It is poor code.

Comment: I don't see why this was downvoted.  OP provides code, expected outcome and actual outcome.

Comment: Please don't forget to mark an answer as accepted, the one wihch suits your answer the most.

Answer (score 8):

This is undefined behavior, so anything can happen. As for what you're observing in particular, here's the explanation:

If an array only has some of its values initialized at declaration, the remaining values are zero.  So your array `a` is `'a', 'b', '\0', '\0', '\0'`. When a pointer to the beginning of this array is interpreted as a 32-bit, little-endian `int`, this has the value 0x00006261, or 25185 in decimal.

Answer (score 4):

*(Disclaimer: the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54641407/4375327) shows you why you get `25185`, this one shows how you can achieve your goal.)*

If you want to output the ASCII value `a[0]` (which seems to be what you're trying to do by `int *p=a;`), tells to `printf()` you want to pass a **`byte`**, and use a **`char*`** (a pointer to a character, which is a byte in C) to point to it:

```
int main (int arg, char **argv)
{
  char a[5] = {'a','b'};
  char *p =a; // points to a char, ie a byte
  printf("%hhx\n", *p); // tells to printf it's a byte type
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char *p =a;` has no alignment problem and no [anti-aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54641362/why-pointer-not-giving-its-ascii-value#comment96074633_54641362) - Good, unlike OP's code.

Answer (score 2):

initializing `a[5]` with `{'a', 'b'}` is giving values to `2` bytes

```
    ascii   binary
a   97      0110 0001
b   98      0110 0010
```

so when you read it via integer pointer it reads `0110 0001 0110 0010 = 25185` (in decimal) and following little endianness upper `2` bytes contains `0`

if you read via char pointer it reads one byte `0110 0001 = 97`